# How to express shared ownership of several individuals

Tags: grammar-choice, genitive

The distinction between shared ownership and private ownership of individuals is well illustrated in *[Dreyer's English: An Utterly Correct Guide to Clarity and Style](https://twitter.com/BCDreyer/status/1382416647592550401/photo/1)*:

> If Jeanette has some pencils and Nelson has some pencils and Jeanette and Nelson are not sharing their pencils, those pencils are:
> `Jeanette’s and Nelson’s pencils`
>
> But if Jeanette and Nelson reject individual ownership and pursue a
> socialist policy of collectivization for the betterment of humankind,
> those pencils are now: `Jeanette and Nelson’s pencils`

How to express this distinction in Latin? Individual ownership can be expressed by genitive case, but how to convey the shared ownership? I can think of using *et...et* pattern:

> Et Quinti et Marci domus est (Quintus and Marcus' house)

Even if this works, will it also work where the property is in plural form: does *Et Quinti et Marci **domus sunt*** imply shared or induvial (each owns a house(s)) ownership?

Comment: I'm not sure that Dreyer's rule really exists in English, even the most formal English. If you and I have shared ownership of a jar of pencils, they're your and my pencils, not you and my pencils. But it might exist in Latin, so let's see what answers you get!

Comment: @BenKovitz, I don't know (and the more I progress with Latin the more I discover I don't really know English). But  I suspect  Dreyer will object and say that "If you and I have shared ownership of a jar of pencils" they are *our* pencils. (your and my pencils are for individual ownership).

Comment: If you're using first person the distinction in English and Latin doesn't seem too clunky, _our_ or _ours_ in English, _noster_ in Latin. Where it gets awkward is second and third person. As a native English speaker I would simply rephrase with a different verb to something like _those pencils belong to Jeanette and Nelson_,

Comment: With Dreyer's example, only the second seems clear to mean that there's shared ownership. Some people might take the first example one way or the other, even if grammatically it's supposed to mean separate ownership.

Comment: Dreyer's distinction seems to be one of those made-up prescriptive rules with no basis in usage. I don't think Latin has a straightforward way of making the semantic distinction either, though in some contexts distributive numerals do something similar. Note that your example phrases with *est/sunt* mean "*it is/they are* Q and M's house(s)", not just "Q and M's house(s)" as translated.